# How can I control the times it appears a popup in WordPress using popupmaker?

Tags: wordpress

I am using Popup maker for wordpress. I need to do the following: I need the popup only appears to the user only one time each 24 hours (obviously the user must be already login in the site).

Any ideas in how can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

one way is using this plugin's hook and use cookie for handle your favorite hours .
i mean, attach a function to appropriate hook of popup maker and write your codes inside it .

Answer (score 0):

Author of Popup Maker here..

Sounds like what your after is already built in. You can create a cookie under the "Cookies" box in the popup editor. Set up one on popup open and a time of "1 day" or "24 hours".

Then edit your auto open trigger and go to the cookie tab and select that newly created cookie.

All set.

Hope that helps.